# Как работает Amazon EC2, как им воспользоваться?

Tags: c++, amazon

*Я мало пока чего еще понимаю в сфере облачных вычислений, поэтому хотел бы задать наверное глупый вопрос.*

Вот у меня есть консольная программа на C++. Она распознает детали на изображении и кое-что с ними делает (обрабатывает). Не суть. Проблема в том, что этих изображений много и мощностей моего ноутбука для выполнения данного алгоритма мне не хватает.

Узнал, что существует такой сервис как Amazon EC2. Честно говоря, не пойму пока что как он  в целом работает. Объясните, пожалуйста. Могу ли я послать ему, к примеру, вот такую задачу и получить ответ: отправляем переменную со значением true. Там проверяется, если true - то вернуть "Hello world"?

Comment: Ок. Вопрос: возможно ли выполнить отправку из моей программы некоторой задачи в сервис Amazon EC2 и после этого получить результат ее выполнения (Для конкретики возьмем такую задачу: Отправляем переменную со значением true. Сервис проверяет, если true, то вернуть "Hello world")?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26576/discussion-on-question-by-----amazon-ec2---).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

фактически, вы запускаете на серверах *amazon*-а виртуальные машины.

причём запуск может осуществляться по требованию — на время вычислений.

управлять всем этим «хозяйством» можно с помощью соответствующего [*api*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html). осуществлять запросы можно [разными способами](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/making-api-requests.html).

**обновление про «облачное» хранилище**

вероятно, для вашей задачи потребуется и «облачное» хранилище, которое также [предоставляется amazon-ом](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/s3/) по протоколу [s3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3).

к нему тоже есть [api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html), которое реализовано в разных клиентах, например, [*s3tools*](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) или [*euca2ools*](https://github.com/eucalyptus/euca2ools).

пример использования такого клиента `s3cmd` из *s3tools* в операционной системе *gnu/linux* можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](https://github.com/sash-kan/rulxfdvd) (правда, там не на *amazon*-овские сервера осуществляется копирование, но по тому же самому протоколу *s3*).

---

по поводу «вернуть "hello world!"»: вот простой пример одновременного выполнения команды на нескольких машинах с операционной системой *gnu/linux*.

здесь используется установленная на моей машине программа `dsh` и три машины с условными именами *host1, host2, host3*, уже настроенными на беспарольный доступ по протоколу *ssh*:

```
$ cat ~/.dsh/machines.conf
host1
host2
host3

$ export var=true
$ dsh -a -c -- 'echo -n "$(hostname): "; if [ "'$var'" = "true" ]; then echo "hello world!"; else echo "not"; fi'
host2: hello world!
host1: hello world!
host3: hello world!

$ export var=bum
$ dsh -a -c -- 'echo -n "$(hostname): "; if [ "'$var'" = "true" ]; then echo "hello world!"; else echo "not"; fi'
host2: not
host1: not
host3: not
```

`dsh` — это всего лишь [одна из множества аналогичных](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/admin/pdsh_parallel.html) по принципу действия программ.