# Git и несколько nginx backend-ов

Tags: git, развертывание

Стоит 3 backend-а, на каждом сейчас приложения версии с master.
Но что делать, когда все-таки некоторые изменения заливаются в репозиторий и все они должны, соответственно, отображаться на всех backend?

Неужели с каждого сервера запускать git pull ходить?
А что если таких серверов под 10 штук?

Comment: Нужна система для деплоя(развертывания) приложения. Я использую Capistrano. Он автоматически сливает изменения с мастер на продакшн сервер.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас развертывание через post-update hook? Предлагаю подумать про систему развертывания (как Махорка предлагает) или хотя бы через git-sync или rsync. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/181472

Comment: Если данный ответ вас устроил, вы можете его принять (галочка рядом с ответом). Если нет — задавайте уточняющие вопросы в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

> А что если таких серверов под 10 штук?

вам поможет автоматизация, которая является «вторым именем» любого *unix*-а.

посмотрите, пожалуйста, приведённый мною [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439394/178576) выполнения команды на нескольких серверах одновременно (во второй половине ответа). там же и ссылка приведена, где упоминаются и другие аналогичные программы.

впрочем, можно обойтись и без дополнительных программ: возможностей **любого** *posix-shell*-а вполне достаточно для подобной автоматизации.