# Установка пакетов на несколько машин одновременно

Tags: debian, ssh, apt-get

Есть сеть из *n* машин под управлением ОС Debian и доступ к ним по ssh. Также есть один диск с репозиторием.

Как параллельно установить набор пакетов с этого диска на все *n* машин?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. на какой-нибудь общедоступной машине «расшариваете» содержимое диска по любому подходящиему протоколу: http, nfs, samba, ftp и т.д.
2. на каждой из *n* машин добавляете соответствующую строчку в `/etc/apt/sources.list` (а лучше — в отдельный файл в `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`).
3. на каждой из *n* машин обновляете список пакетов (`sudo apt-get update`).
4. на кажлой из *n* машин устанавливаете нужные пакеты (`sudo apt-get install ...`).

как выполнить одну и ту же команду на множестве машин параллельно, я описывал, например, здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439394/178576

Comment: [HOWTO: репозиторий Debian](http://l10n-russian.alioth.debian.org/repository-howto.ru.html)

Answer (score 0):

ansible/puppet/chief/salt/etc ?